# How to create a prism using the API

Tags: python

I am surprised at how difficult it is to do elementary things with the  blender api, or at least find the information on the web to do elementary things like lines, texts and in the case, a prism.
So I hope to make a great contribution to the blender community with this question and in general with every question I ask because I'm starting from scratch and I think is the case of many people.
I suspect that the way to do it is through a cube.

Comment: This question seems too vague - what *specifically* are you trying to achieve? Technically, a cube is a prism so running 'bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()' would add a *square prism* to the scene. There are API calls to create a mesh from a set of points in 3D space and this could easily be used in a python function to create a generic prism. Add some detail of what you've achieved so far and a specific problem you're stuck on. See https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Three_ways_to_create_objects for an example of creating a mesh from a set of points.

Comment: @RichSedman if the "fluff" was edited out of this question it would be the title again.

Comment: Enable the Extra Objects addon, look through the addons code to see how to create more complex meshes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use add primitive cylinder to make a [prism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism_(geometry))**

Basically by definition a cylinder in blender is really a regular ngon prism.  Therefore, to add a prism via the UI, simply *`add > mesh > cylinder`* with the amount of sides you want the ngon end to have. For example for a triangular prism

[image]

This is a simple call to the  operator:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(vertices=3)
```

change the value of vertices to make other ngons on the ends of prism.

**And via the bmesh API with [bmesh.ops.create_cone](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.create_cone)**

Rather than having a create cylinder bmesh has a create cone, which allows us to create a prism by setting the end radii the same.  Simple code to add a triangular prism.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
context = bpy.context
bm = bmesh.new()
bmesh.ops.create_cone(bm, 
        cap_ends=True, 
        cap_tris=False, 
        segments=3, 
        diameter1=1, 
        diameter2=1, 
        depth=2)
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("Prism")
bm.to_mesh(mesh)
prism = bpy.data.objects.new("Prism", mesh)
# link to scene
context.scene.objects.link(prism)
```